# Error al crear un bloque de codigo html que incluye un canvas

Tags: php, jquery, canvas

Buenas necesito algún apoyo de la comunidad Tengo la siguiente situación:
Necesito consultar unos datos X y con los mismos crear un grafico desde mi controladora.
Para luego enviarle los datos a la vista.
Estoy Utilizando php.
Realizo mi consulta y al realizar las verificaciones, el grafico canvas se muestra correctamente, pero al pasarlo para un modal en boostrap solo me trae los datos de la descripción. No llega a mostrar el grafico ya elaborado desde mi Controladora.

El problema :

```
introducir el código aquí /* Para Consultas de la Calidad con Fecha pasada por parametros */
public function actionGetDataCalidad(){
    //Calidad y Graficos
    if($_POST['querydate'] != ''){
        /* Aqui se pinta con FECHA */
       
        
        $limit = '5';

        $yearMonthParame = explode(' ', $_POST['querydate']);
        $mesParame = $this->getMonthNumber($yearMonthParame[0]);
        $yearParame = $yearMonthParame[1];

        $la_calidadconFecha = CalidadServicio::model()->findAll([
            'condition' => 'MONTH(fecha_calidad) = :mes AND YEAR(fecha_calidad) = :ano',
            'params' => [
                ':mes' => $mesParame,
                ':ano' => $yearParame,
            ],
            'limit' => $limit,
        ]);
        
              $outPutGraf ='';                                          

            for( $i=0; $i< count($la_calidadconFecha ); $i++ )
            {
                
                $outPutGraf .= '
                <div class="col-3" style="width:200px; height:200px; margin-bottom:50px;">
                    <div id="GraficoConvertido" style="width:195px; height:195px; margin-left:5px;" >
                        <canvas class="myGraf" alt="MyGrafd" width=185 height=185 id="GraficoId'.$i.'"></canvas>
                            <script>
                                let ArrayValoresCalidadFecha'.$i.' =[];
                                
                                ArrayValoresCalidadFecha'.$i.'.push('.$la_calidadconFecha[$i]->Porciento.');
                                console.log(ArrayValoresCalidadFecha'.$i.');
                                var canvas=document.getElementById("GraficoId'.$i.'");
                                var graficoConvertido = document.getElementById("GraficoConvertido");
                                var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

                                var colors=["#00067F","gray","#4AC5FA"];
                                var values'.$i.'=[ArrayValoresCalidadFecha'.$i.'[0],0,100 - ArrayValoresCalidadFecha'.$i.'[0]];
                                

                                var labels=[];
    
                                dmbChart(80,80,70,20,values'.$i.',colors,labels,0);

                                function dmbChart(cx,cy,radius,arcwidth,values'.$i.',colors,labels,selectedValue){
                                    var tot=0;
                                    var accum=0;
                                    var PI=Math.PI;
                                    var PI2=PI*2;
                                    var offset=-PI/2;
                                    ctx.lineWidth=arcwidth;
                                    for(var i=0;i<values'.$i.'.length;i++){tot+=values'.$i.'[i];}
                                    for(var i=0;i<values'.$i.'.length;i++){
                                        ctx.beginPath();
                                        ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,
                                            offset+PI2*(accum/tot),
                                            offset+PI2*((accum+values'.$i.'[i])/tot)
                                        );
                                        ctx.strokeStyle=colors[i];
                                        ctx.stroke();
                                        accum+=values'.$i.'[i];
                                    }
                                    var innerRadius=radius-arcwidth-3;
                                    ctx.beginPath();
                                    ctx.arc(cx,cy,innerRadius,100.5,PI2); //100.5 es para borrar el circulo de adentro poner 0 para ver la de nuevo
                                    ctx.fillStyle=colors[selectedValue];
                                    ctx.fill();
                                    ctx.textAlign="center";
                                    ctx.textBaseline="bottom";
                                    ctx.fillStyle="#00067F";
                                    ctx.font=(innerRadius)+"px arial";
                                    ctx.fillText(values'.$i.'[selectedValue]+"%",cx,cy+innerRadius*.5);
                                    //Convertir el Grafico elaborado en una Imagen sin resultados
                                    
                                    
                                }
                                
                            </script>
                            
                            <p class="texto">  '.$la_calidadconFecha[$i]->descripcion.' </p>
   
                    </div>
                </div>
                ';

            }
            echo $outPutGraf;


    }
    


}
```

Ahora le muestro mi solicitud ajax con jquery donde claramente utilizo el innerHtml. El Resultado es que Me trae solos los datos de la descripción y no llega a pintar el canvas. Vale destacar que los nodos se llegan a insertar en DOM:

```
introducir el código aquí /* Función para actualizar al mismo tiempo el Container de Calidad de Servicios */
    function enviarGraf(query){
                $.ajax({
                url: "index.php?r=site/getDataCalidad",
                method: "POST",
                data: {querydate:  query},
                success: function (data) {
            
                    if(data == null){
                        var modal =document.getElementById('exampleModal');
                        var seccionCalidad = modal.querySelector('#idContainerConsultaSerCalidad').innerHTML='No se encontraron resultados para la fecha seleccionada';
                        
                    }else{
                        var modalidad =document.getElementById('exampleModal');
                        modalidad.querySelector('#idContainerConsultaSerCalidad').innerHTML = data;
                        
                        
                    }
                }
                });   
    }
```

Les Muestro el Resultado En Foto
[image: Resultado que muestra el modal]
Alguna Sugerencia?? Please